# Trigger LaunchFile even if WiX installer version is lower than installed one

Tags: wix

I've got a WiX installer which contains the following lines:

```
<CustomAction Id='LaunchFile' FileKey='MyApp' Return='asyncNoWait' />
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action='LaunchFile' After='InstallFinalize'></Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

When I run the installer, all goes well and my installed application launches at the end.

Now, if the application is already installed and I try to run an older version of the installer, I get a message such as "A newer version is already installed", and the installation aborts.

However in that case, I would like to know if there is a way to silently skip the installation, but still launch the already installed application at the end.

Note: I'm aware of the `AllowSameVersionUpgrades` and `AllowDowngrades` attributes on the [MajorUpgrade](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/majorupgrade.html) element but, if possible, I would like to avoid downgrading the installed version.

Answer (score 0):

You can check for your version and then store in a property , then do something like this :

```
   <Custom Action="ChangeSqlStringToWindowsAuthentication" After='InstallFinalize'>NOT Install AND  (<![CDATA[APPPOOLIDENTITYDOMAIN <>"SqlAuthentication"]]>)</Custom>
```